# Why (many objects in objects) faster than (many elements in one object)?

Tags: javascript, performance, object

I have ~16.000 items (one item is an array, has 6 values). All items have 5 "attributes", they're numbers. I need to store them, and when I know the attributes, return the item, as fast as possible. I tried 2 kind of methods:

1. Objects in objects. If `a = attribute1`, `b = attribute2` ... to `e`, then I can get the item the user's looking for by `data1[a][b][c][d][e]`. The full data stored in this format: http://jpst.it/z12-
2. One object, but it has 16k arrays, the object's properties are the given item's attributes. Then `myItem = data2[""+a+b+c+d+e]`. http://jpst.it/z13p

I ran some tests to see which method is the faster:

```
var test,
    a = 30175,
    b = 5,
    c = 1,
    d = 1,
    e = 60,
    abcde = 301755360;
console.time("test1");
for (var i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
    test = data1[a][b][c][d][e];
console.timeEnd("test1");
console.time("test2");
for (var i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
    test = data2[abcde];
console.timeEnd("test2");
```

Results on my PC:

```
            test1       test2
Firefox:    1482.00ms   1341.00ms
Chrome:     665.00ms    424.00ms
Explorer:   12555.17ms  4945,50ms
```

The second method is always faster. But why? I ran another test to know how many times the JS have to check if the given object's key equals to the needed key:

```
var x = 0;
function fn(obj, myKey) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        x++;
        if (key == myKey)
            return obj[key];
    }
}
```

Method 1: `fn(fn(fn(fn(fn(data1, a), b), c), d), e);` => `x` is 352.
Method 2: `fn(data2, abcde);` => `x` is 3154.
However, method 2 isn't 10x slower, it's even faster.

Comment: you're dealing with nested arrays, which means JS has to do the array lookup calculations, existence checks, etc.. for every level of the array. e.g. your test1 is doing 9999999 * 5 array = 49,999,995 lookups, while test2 is doing only 9,999,999

Comment: The first one, it is doing multiple operations. A search for each key. The second is just one operation.

Comment: You notice that `abcde = 301755360;` is not unique?

Comment: Uh, to access a property, JavaScript does not enumerate all properties and compare their names to the searched one…

Comment: @Bergi: this is just an example, I removed everything that isn't needed.

Comment: 1) As it stands, the comparison you're doing means quite nothing -too far from a real use-case-. 2) one access is done in about 0,0002 ms : are you sure the performance issue is the access ? 3) question : Do you have a fixed range for each of the attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

This might give you an idea of what's going on. 2nd getter is called 9 times, first getter is called 45 times. Each time it first has to access 30186, then 6, then ... 5 calls for each iteration to get the value.

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var data1 = {"30186":{"6":{"1":{"1":{"0":[4,1430745862,"3 - 5 ref","4 ref","4 ref",1]}}}}};
var data2 = {"3018663":[4,1430745862,"3 - 5 ref","4 ref","4 ref",1]};

Object.prototype.get = function(i) { x++; console.log(i); return this[i]; }
Object.prototype.get2 = function(i) { y++; return this[i]; }

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    test = data1.get(30186).get(6).get(1).get(1).get(0);

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    test = data2.get2(3018663);

console.log(x, y);
```